# How to emit message on Start()? (Socket.io)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am trying to pass in some data to the server when it initially connects, but emitting doesn't seem to work in Start. However, if I run it during Update, the emit works. I'm guessing this has something to do with the order in which scripts are executed, so that my script executes after the socket connects.

I have tried changing the order in scripts and adding a delay to when Start executes through Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order but to no avail.

Server:

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Someone connected')
    socket.on('player-connect', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Client:

```cs
public SocketIOComponent socket; //The socket script

void Start()
{
    socket.Emit("player-connect"); //Connect to the server
}
```

It's expected that the Emit function sends to the server, and the server logs it (in this case it's undefined but I'm planning to add in data), just like how it works when the emit is called in Update.

EDIT: 
I understand that I could just use a boolean to check if it's called, and simply call it in Update, but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it after the client is actually connected.

```
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () => {
    socket.Emit("player-connect");
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to find how to use events anywhere online, and Socket is not defined... Any ideas?